# React/Redux frontend communicating with Node.js API Auth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt, cloudant

I have a react/redux app that I want to communicate with a Node.js app (probably Express) through its API. The Node.js app has a CloudantDB and contains sensitive info. Each user can only access his/her part of the DB.

How would you recommend I **secure the API endpoints and establish a user Auth**? I was thinking to use **Passport.js** on the Node.js app and have it interact with a **Jason Web Token Auth** on the react side.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mat, request for recommend a library or tool is 'off topic' in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.

Token, Cookies, JWT

JWT is the most simplest way, (I think) and the most feature rich..

But its up to you..

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @webdeb, I thought so too but can I restrict what portions of the database each user has access to with JWTs? Eg. each user has a secret string in their db json object, can I make it so each user can only see his/her string?

Comment: @Mat this is the part of you business logic

Comment: what do you mean? I thought tokens gave the user access to the entire API, so they could very easily make a get call to another doctors data and retrieve it with their token...

Comment: @Mat well I dont understand your problem, if you have a jwt Token you can store the Information you Need in the Token, so if a request comes in, you just check if this User is authorized or not.. Should be not that Hard to implement

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy which is an express based app that you can extend to use Passport.js

Most importantly it limits the scope of what a user can pull from the DB and store in browser.